# Lodash mergeWith not giving desired output using customizer

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm using lodash with nodejs -

```js
function customizer(objValue, srcValue, key) {
  if (key === 'required' && _.isArray(objValue) && _.isArray(srcValue)) {
    return _.intersection(objValue, srcValue);
  }
}

var a = { 
  'a': {
    'required': [1,2,3]
  }, 
  'b': {
    'required': [1,3]
  },
  'c': {
    'd': {
      'e': {
        'f': {
          'required': [4,5]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var b = { 
  'a': {
    'required': [1,2]
  }, 
  'b': {
    'required': [1,2,3]
  }
}

let c = {}
console.log(_.mergeWith(c, a, b, customizer));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Right now it's giving me following output -

```
{ 
  'a': { 
    'required': [1,2] 
  }, 
  'b': { 
    'required': [1,3] 
  }, 
  c: { 
    d: { 
      e: { 
        f: { 
          'required': [4,5] 
        } 
      } 
    } 
  } 
}
```

But I need following output -

```
{ 
  'a': { 
    'required': [1,2] 
  }, 
  'b': { 
    'required': [1,3] 
  }, 
  c: { 
    d: { 
      e: { 
        f: { 
          'required': [] 
        } 
      } 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Basically I wanted to make values for required key empty if it's not common. My real life scenario is merging two templates where couple of keys might different. I wanted to keep those key-value pairs but wants to set `required` as empty for those fields.

Comment: Your condition is `_.isArray(objValue) && _.isArray(srcValue)` but only one of those is an array, the other is `undefined`. So, it doesn't go inside the `if`. The library works exactly as expected here.

Comment: That's true. Is there any other way to achieve the same?

Comment: Not with this approach. You want the array to be empty if the key doesn't have a value. Which is *always* true for all instances of the key "required" because `c` doesn't have any of it. It's easier to merge `a` and `b` first using one set of rules, merge that into `c` using another set of rules. However, it's not quite clear if that is really the solution you're looking for. It's not, according to the logic laid out in the question. But that same logic also disqualifies the expected result.